# Trouble displaying a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a Table with one of the column names AS a user defined function. I have successfully inserted data into the table but I can't select and view the whole table.

```
CREATE TABLE Member_Profile(
Gender          CHAR(1),
Name            VARCHAR(50),
D_O_B           DATE,
Weight          DECIMAL(10,2),
Height          DECIMAL(10,2),
Smoker          CHAR(1),
Salary          INT,
MemberID        INT,
Cupid_Score AS  [dbo].[Q3CupidUDF](Gender,Name,D_O_B,Weight,Height,Smoker,Salary),
PRIMARY KEY(MemberID)
)

INSERT INTO Member_Profile VALUES('M', 'Tim', '01-01-82', 97.0, 1.88, 'N', 65000, 1)
SELECT * FROM Member_Profile
```

This is the UDF for the table----

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Q3CupidUDF]
(
@Gender         CHAR(1),
@Name           VARCHAR(15),
@DOB            DATE,
@Weight         DECIMAL(10,2),
@Height         DECIMAL(10,2),
@Smoker         CHAR(1),
@Salary         INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @CupidScore INT
DECLARE @Age INT
SELECT @Age = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @DOB, GETDATE())

SELECT @CupidScore = CASE   
    WHEN @Age between 20 and 30 THEN 5
    WHEN @Age between 31 and 40 THEN 4
    WHEN @Age between 41 and 50 THEN 3
    WHEN @Age > 50 THEN 2
    ELSE 0
END

DECLARE @WtHt DECIMAL(2,1)
SET @WtHt = @Weight/(@Height*@Height)

SET @CupidScore = @CupidScore + CASE
    WHEN @WtHt between 20 and 25 THEN 1
    WHEN @WtHt between 25 and 30 THEN 3                     
    WHEN @WtHt between 30 and 35 THEN 4
    WHEN @WtHt between 35 and 40 THEN 2
    ELSE 0
END

IF @Smoker = 'Y' SET @CupidScore = @CupidScore + 2

SET @CupidScore = @CupidScore + CASE
    WHEN @Salary < 50000 THEN 1
    WHEN @Salary between 50001 and 60000 THEN 2
    WHEN @Salary between 60001 and 70000 THEN 3
    WHEN @Salary > 70000 THEN 4
END

RETURN @CupidScore
END
```

Comment: can you show the sql for the UDF?

Comment: This is the error I receive when performing the select statement 'Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.'

Comment: Why are you using DECIMAL(2,1) when you are dividing and multiplying DECIMAL(10,2)?

Comment: The result of that calculation is `27.444`

Comment: That was an accident, just changed it to DECIMAL(10,2) and the SELECT * statement works but now the CupidScore column says null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is due to data truncation inside the UDF. The problem is that the calculation you are doing returns a decimal value with a lot more places than you have declared in your variable.

```
DECLARE @WtHt DECIMAL(2,1)
```

Should be declared as:

```
DECLARE @WtHt decimal(10,7)
```

This is because the following calculation returns a value like this: `27.444545043006`

```
SET @WtHt = @Weight/(@Height*@Height)
```

Here is a working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a874f/1/0

Comment: That does solve my arithmetic error but I don't understand why the cupid score is null now

Comment: O thanks, it doesn't seem to work for a salary of 50000, must have gone wrong somewhere --- I see, should have salary < 50001 not < 50000. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have this: `WHEN @Salary < 50000 THEN 1`. It should be this: `WHEN @Salary <= 50000 THEN 1`. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a874f/1/0

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got SQL server on front of me, but have you tried changing @wtht to be decimal (10, 2)?